# Redirect url from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

My django view is like this:

```
def example(request, id):
    context = {}
    if id:
        context['redirect_url'] = '/foo/' + str(id) + '/'
    else:
        context['success'] = True
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

I call this method using ajax from one page say lets say 'index.html'

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        if(data.success==true){
            # Do something here    
        }else{
            window.location.replace(data.redirect_url)
        };
    }
});
```

Everything is all right when *'success'* in *'context'* is **True**. But when it is not true and redirect url is assigned and it is redirected to that 'redirect_url' ie from javascript. After it is called it callbacks the example view and gives the json response in browser. What I want is ajax response in the page from which I started ie in *'index.html'*.

Here 'redirect_url' ie '/foo/1/' mentioned in 'example' view is calling some another view not 'example' view itself.

Comment: I don't understand. It's doing exactly what you have asked it to do: redirect to the given URL. What do you want instead?

Comment: After it is redirected to redirect_url again request view is called and json response can be seen on browser. I dont want json response on browser. I want response as we get when we call ajax request. And that response should be in that page from which i started.

Comment: But if you don't want to redirect, *don't redirect*. Why are you doing that call to `window.location.replace` if you don't want to change the window location?

Comment: Lets say I am on the page X. I called that ajax request. I was redirected to 'foo'. Now again when foo completes 'foo' redirects to 'example' view. And that example view gives me response in my browser i.e just json on my screen. I want that json to be loaded on page X from which I have started. My code might be wrong. What can be done to do so? Sorry for unclear question. :(

Comment: I want to load the final json to first page from where i requested ajax request. Can jsonp solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you need to perform a redirect ? Can't you just generate the expected JSON when id is defined in your example view ?

Comment: redirect is for login using OAuth2